# Error on xml file

Tags: xml

When I open my comment feed, this type of error pops up.
I'm trying to put this file into a database, but that's beside the point.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

I was guessing this is a programming message, therefore I was compelled to post it on this forum.
I was hoping that one of you experts would be able to figure out what this means.
I know this is a bad question and it may waste your time, but I am very curious. I will apologise in advance.

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: It was on a website I was trying to get the database from.

Comment: It's common for a web browser to throw errors like this, but then again web browsers aren't built to read XML files. Try opening the feed in a proper feed reader and it should work just fine.

Comment: The link is this: http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/all-c_ent.xml                           For example

Comment: Works fine for me (Mozilla Firefox 39.0.3) so try different browser.

Comment: Oh, I was using Google Chrome, therefore it didn't work, but it works on my safari. Thanks mate.